# Parse JSON file without having to save it in a file

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have a command that returns a JSON dump that won't get saved into any file.

I have to parse a particular field from the JSON response without saving the output.

I am able to achieve it if I save the output of the command and then parse it using `jq` and `grep` like this:

```
platform json_dump platform_id >resp.json
jq . resp.json | grep elbName
```

But, I do not want to write the output of my command platform `json_dump platform_id` which is a JSON dump into any file. I want to parse the `elbName` directly from the out of the command.

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try another pipe to pass the result to jq command

```
platform json_dump platform_id | jq .elbName
```

Comment: It throws an error `jq: Unknown option --no-client`

Comment: can you give me an example json to test with in my side and update the awnser ?

Answer (score 2):

Just pipe the program's output to jq:

```
platform json_dump platform_id | jq .elbName
```

or whatever.

PS: Use jq to get the value you want, not grep. Example of doing that.:

```
$ echo '{"elbName":"foo"}' | jq .elbName
"foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have python :)

```
platform json_dump platform_id | python -c 'import sys,json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["elbName"])' # a bit long ? :)
```